# Hide "X has signed in" messages in Teamviewer 9

Tags: teamviewer

I'm using Teamview 9.  Frequently, Teamviewer opens a little message box stating "X has signed in". How can I hide these boxes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually,

In Extras -> Options -> Computers & Contacts there is "Notify me when partners sign in" among other checkboxes. You could uncheck it if you do not want to be notified when some of your saved computers signs in.

Answer (score 1):

If using a Mac, open System Preferences > Notifications > Teamviewer and set notifications to "None".

Comment: This is a usefull answer if the user is, indeed, using a Mac. Best would be to include also the method to do so under Windows. So your answer would be complete and really usefull.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) needs to be expanded.  Please edit it to explain *why* your solution addresses the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to accomplish this. There's a similar question [here](http://teamviewerforums.com/index.php?topic=1185.0). For obvious reasons, you can't hide this *completely* on the host machine. However, you can force it to minimize.

`Extras > Options > Advanced > Show advanced options > Automatically minimize local TeamViewer Panel`